# Getting error object object when using ajax to pass parameters to my servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

So I am having an issue that my ajax is going directly to the error call, I understand that I don't have anything in my success call however I would expect the page to return the messages from my servlet when correct or incorrect data is given. the popup dialog returns this message

```
error: [object Object] status: error er:
```

ajax-

```
function sendAjax(){
    var article = new Object();
    article.username = $('#username').val();
    article.password = $('#password').val();        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/FishingTrax/LoginServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(article),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {

        },
        error:function(data,status,er) {
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);

        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

servlet-

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if(databaseConnection.checkUser(username, password))
    {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("Username or Password incorrect");
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
        rs.include(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a reason the error method takes a status parameter.  Its impossible to troubleshoot without knowing what status was returned.

Comment: this was the message returned error: [object Object] status: error er:

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax request you expect the sever to send `json` data. But as far as i can see your server is not providing `json` but `html` data. That should cause the error.